# Prove or disprove For all real numbers x, there exists a positive real number ε such that either x<=(-ε ) OR x>=ε

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm just learning about quantifiers and proofs and I can't seem to get this practice question. I tried writing the negation to there exists a real number x such that for positive real numbers ε , -ε

Comment: French mathematicians might regard this as true, but most others would say it was false.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is only true if $x=0$ is excluded, as Jasper has stated.

Once that is done, it's as simple as choosing $\varepsilon = \frac{|x|}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent statements to the negation of the proposition to be proved or disproved are:

$$\neg \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+,x\leq -\epsilon \lor x \geq \epsilon\\
\iff \exists x\in\mathbb{R},\neg \exists\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+,x\leq -\epsilon \lor x \geq \epsilon\\
\iff \exists x\in\mathbb{R},\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+,\neg (x\leq -\epsilon \lor x \geq \epsilon)\\
\iff \exists x\in\mathbb{R},\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+, (x > -\epsilon \land x < \epsilon)\\
\iff \exists x\in\mathbb{R},\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+, |x|<\epsilon.$$

There does exist a real number whose absolute value is less than all positive real numbers, namely $0$ (and further more $0$ is the only such real number).

Thus the proposition $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exists\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+,x\leq -\epsilon \lor x \geq \epsilon$ must be false.